# "Cannot find namespace 'Objects' " when Objects class and/or namespace exists

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a classes, `Initialize` and a file `Objects` with a `player` class and constructor.
The `initialize` class is as follows:

```cs
using System;
namespace ConsoleTagGame{

    public class initialize{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Objects.Player player1 = new Objects.Player("test player", false, false);
            Console.WriteLine(player1.name);
        }
    }
}
```

and the `objects` file is:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleTagGame/*.Objects*/{

    // Actual player object
    public class Player{
        // player properties
        string Name {   get;    set;    }
        bool IsAlive {  get;    set;    }
        bool IsIt { get;    set;    }

        // constructor
        public Player(string name, bool isAlive, bool isIt){
            this.Name = name;
            this.IsAlive = isAlive;
            this.IsIt = isIt;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I have tried removing `Object.` from declaring the variable, still gives essentially same results)

Whenever I try and run it, I get the error `The type or namespace name "Objects" could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` (CS0246 for reference). Im not sure if this is because im not running an IDE and am just using a text editor & terminal, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The first detail is to note that when a property is used by another class that does not directly inherit, it is necessary to use the "public" directive.

```
namespace ConsoleTagGame.Objects
{

Actual player object
    public class Player
    {
        // player properties
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsAlive { get; set; }
        public bool IsIt { get; set; }

        // constructor
        public Player(string name, bool isAlive, bool isIt)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.IsAlive = isAlive;
            this.IsIt = isIt;
        }
    }
}
```

Another point is that in the initialize class you are referencing the Player class by the path Objects.Player, whereas in the Player class its namespace is ConsoleTagGame instead of ConsoleTagGame.Objects, as in the example above.

Finally the initialize class would look like this:

```
using ConsoleTagGame.Objects;
   using System;

namespace ConsoleTagGame
{
    public class initialize
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player player1 = new Player("test player", false, false);
            Console.WriteLine(player1.Name);
        }
    }
}
```